# constructors and abstract classes in java

Tags: java, constructor, null, abstract-class, super

I have an abstract class `Entity.java` and a class which extends this, `Magician.java`. Whenever I create a `new Magician("Ged", 300)`; and then call `System.out.println()` it always prints `null(0)`, and I'm not sure why when it should print Ged(300). Here is the relevant code:

**Entity** fields/ constructor:

```
public abstract class Entity {

    protected String name;
    protected int lifePoints = 0;

    public Entity(String name, int lifePoints) {
        assert (lifePoints >= 0);
        this.name = name;
        this.lifePoints = lifePoints;
    }

    ...

}
```

**Magician** fields/ Constructor/ toString:

```
public class Magician extends Entity implements SpellCaster {

    public Magician(String name, int lifePoints) {
        super(name, lifePoints);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    protected String name;
    protected int lifePoints;

    ...

    public String toString() {
        return name + "(" + lifePoints + ")";
    }

}
```

**Main** class:

```
public static void main(String[]args) {

    Magician m1=new Magician("Ged",300);
    System.out.println(m1.toString());
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's because you've re-declared the `name` and `lifePoints` variable in `Magician` class, and not initializing it.

Comment: What do you mean? New to this site, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not initializing

```
protected String name;
protected int lifePoints;
```

of your Magician class

```
public Magician(String name, int lifePoints) {
    super(name, lifePoints); // initializing fields of parent(Entity) not of child(Magician)
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
```

Also, protected should be used in Parent class, not in the child. Please revisit the basics of Java.

Answer (score 3):

You are shadowing the super class `Entity`'s instance fields `name` and `lifePoints` in the sub class `Magician`.

And those by by default set to `null` and 0 respectively. Remove those instance fields declaration from sub class `Magician`.

```
public class Magician extends Entity implements SpellCaster {

   public Magician(String name, int lifePoints) {
    super(name, lifePoints);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
   }


    ...

    public String toString(){
       return name + "(" + lifePoints + ")";
    }

}
```